# Swift arrays of Swift dictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, dictionary

I have this array that I initialize as just an empty array:

```
var dataArray:[Any] = []
```

I add dictionaries to the `dataArray`, and it looks like this:

```
[[onlineStatus: Offline, whatDoing: , gamerTag: KgLui720, id: 2533274926939486], [onlineStatus: Offline, whatDoing: , gamerTag: BigBear46, id: 2533274801083843], [onlineStatus: Online, whatDoing: Watching TV, gamerTag: PeeMilroy12, id: 2533274975595658], [onlineStatus: Offline, whatDoing: , gamerTag: BR0, id: 2533275031633640], [onlineStatus: Offline, whatDoing: , gamerTag: jerrycia224, id: 2533274959352491]]
```

An array of dictionaries:

```
var index = 0

while index < dataArray.count{
    let row = table.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as tableRowController
    let theScreenName:NSString = dataArray[index]["gamerTag"]
    row.screenNameLabel.setText(theScreenName)
    index++
}
```

This gives the error:

```
'Any' does not have a member named subscript
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more specific about what your array can store, which are objects with `String` keys and `AnyObject` values. So, the syntax for that data type would be `[String: AnyObject]`. This should allow you to use subscript notation:

```
var dataArray: [[String: AnyObject]] = []
```

You could also cast it:

```
let theScreenName: NSString = (dataArray[index] as [String: AnyObject])["gamerTag"]
```

However, your code will be more coherent if you make it evident that that's your intention from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Im still having a little trouble. The 'let theScreenName' code you gave me says 'Int' is not convertible to 'Range<int>'

Comment: @GregPappok Did you try the replacing the first line of code in your question with the first one I gave here and leaving that part as it is before trying the first part? That's the way I'd recommend.

Comment: Yes I did. I just figured it out:
            let theScreenName: NSString = (dataArray[index] as [String: AnyObject])["gamerTag"] as NSString
worked for me. Thanks!